# How can I cross lines of a listA.txt and listB.txt and return an output.txt with each line of listB.txt where they match in Python and grep?

Tags: python, regex

So, I have two lists with emails and I want to cross that information.

The "listA.txt" list will be used as a basis for checking the "listB.txt" list, where there are not only emails but also texts. Then an "output.txt" file will be generated, where there will be the WHOLE line where that email listed in "listA.txt" appears in "listB.txt".

Example:

```
listA.txt     

arthur@gmail.com
guinevere@outlook.com
lancelot@yahoo.com
gawaine@gmail.com

listB.txt

arthur@gmail.com Arthur Smith
guinevere@outlook.comtest
lance@gmail.com
gawaine@gmail.com Ocean Bvd
arth@hotmail.com

output.txt

arthur@gmail.com Arthur Smith
guinevere@outlook.comtest
gawaine@gmail.com Ocean Bvd
```

Note that I need each line of "listA.txt" as a pattern to check not only the lines of "listB.txt" that contain ALL the whole line of "listA.txt", but also return ALL the whole line of "listB.txt" where those emails appear at "output.txt". I don't want partial results as has already happened with another algorithms where "lancelot@yahoo.com" was split (splitlines) and matched with "lance@gmail.com".

I searched for more than a week, including here on the stackoverflow, but I didn't get any solution and I have no idea what to do, could you help me? I've tried grep, regex and etc. but no success too.

My try:

```
with open('emails4.txt', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as k: 
keywords = k.read().splitlines() 
results = [] 

with open('emails5.txt', encoding="latin-1") as f, open('output.txt', 'w', 
encoding="latin-1") as o: 
keywords2 = f.read().splitlines() 
for line in keywords2: 
if any(line in key for key in keywords):
o.write(line + "\n")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I've tried ..." - please provide that tries

Comment: `code`

with open('emails4.txt', 'r', encoding="latin-1") as k:
    keywords = k.read().splitlines()

results = []

with open('emails5.txt', encoding="latin-1") as f, open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="latin-1") as o:
    keywords2 = f.read().splitlines()
    for line in keywords2:
        if any(line in key for key in keywords):
            o.write(line + "\n")
`code`

Comment: I mean, next time put that information directly in the question (you can edit the question also now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
A = [
    "arthur@gmail.com",
    "guinevere@outlook.com",
    "lancelot@yahoo.com",
    "gawaine@gmail.com",
]

B = [
    "arthur@gmail.com Arthur Smith",
    "guinevere@outlook.comtest",
    "lance@gmail.com",
    "gawaine@gmail.com Ocean Bvd",
    "arth@hotmail.com",
]

# oneliner
output = [b for b in B if any(b.startswith(a) for a in A)]
print(output)

# "longer" solution
output = []
for b in B:
    for a in A:
        if b.startswith(a):
            output.append(b)
            break
print(output)
```

The complexity is quadratic - `len(A)*len(B)`

EDIT: solution with files:

```py
with open("listA.txt") as f: listA = f.read().splitlines()
with open("listB.txt") as f: listB = f.read().splitlines()
output = [b for b in listB if any(b.startswith(a) for a in listA)]
with open("output.txt","w") as f: f.writelines(l+"\n" for l in output)
```

Comment: Right but how can I do this using files? How should I handle these files?